# How to unhide Titlebar and Frame of Pidgin or any application in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, window-management, pidgin

I played with the application settings of Pidgin and now Pidgin doesn't have any titlebar and frame. I did this with "Right Click on the title bar>More Actions>Special Application Settings>Appearance & Fixes>Checked No Titlebar and frame. How can I undo this? I tried right clicking the application from the taskbar (since I can't right click it on the application because it has no titlebar) but it doesn't show "More Actions".

Comment: Which window manager/desktop environment are you using? E.g. Mate, Cinnamon, KDE, …

Comment: Is it really important?

Comment: Yes it is important. I am using KWin.

Answer (score 0):

These sort of settings for individual applications or windows are known as KWin Rules stored in KDE/Plasma config file `kwinrulesrc`. They're accessible from `System Settings`->`Windows Management`->`Window Rules`. Alternatively, from command line: `kcmshell5 kwinrules`.